# How to customize link style in Table of contents using titletoc?

Tags: table-of-contents, hyperref, titletoc

I want to customize the links (appearance) in the TOC. In the entire document I use 'hidelinks' in hyperref (to turn of the box), and then have some fancy own link visualization (here for MWE replaced by `dotuline`).

So I changed the TOC Format to include hyperlinks. I turned on the "link boxes" for debugging and the result does not look good. For the number the click area is too short, and for label it goes wrong competely.

[image]
**MWE:**

```
    \documentclass{book}
    \usepackage{titletoc}
    \usepackage{hyperref}
    \usepackage{ulem} 
    \titlecontents{chapter}[1pc]%
      {\addvspace{2ex}\Large\filright}%
      {\hyperlink{chapter.\thecontentslabel}{\dotuline{\thecontentslabel}}{1pc}}{\hspace*{-1pc}}%
      {\titlerule*[1pc]{.}\hyperlink{chapter.\thecontentslabel}{\dotuline{\contentspage}}}[]

    \begin{document}
    Link Customization: \hyperlink{chapter.1}{\dotuline{Jump to chapter 1}} 
    \tableofcontents
    \chapter{Dummy1}
    dummy
    \end{document}
```

**Original TOC:**

[image]

**With:**

```
    \titlecontents{chapter}[1pc]%
      {\addvspace{2ex}\Large\filright}%
      {\contentslabel[\thecontentslabel]{1pc}}{\hspace*{-1pc}}%
      {\titlerule*[1pc]{.}\contentspage}[]
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an attempt to mimick the `titletoc` specified looks. However there is a bit of guess work for what `titletoc` uses for the right margin.

Package `titlesec` is loaded for using `\titlerule` command.

Links with `\dotuline` decoration from `ulem` are put in the Toc via `etoc` package.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{ulem} 
\usepackage{hyperref}

% Code from OP with titletoc
% \usepackage{titletoc}
% \titlecontents
%   {chapter}% section name
%   [1pc]% left margin
%   {\addvspace{2ex}\Large\filright}% above code
%   {\hyperlink{chapter.\thecontentslabel}%
%              {\dotuline{\thecontentslabel}}{1pc}}% numbered entry format
%   {\hspace*{-1pc}}% number-less entry format
%   {\titlerule*[1pc]{.}%
%    \hyperlink{chapter.\thecontentslabel}%
%              {\dotuline{\contentspage}}}% filler page format

\usepackage{titlesec}% to use \titlerule command
\usepackage{etoc}

\makeatletter % to use \@tocrmarg and \@pnumwidth from the LaTeX book class
\etocsetstyle 
        {chapter}
        {\Large\leftskip 1pc \rightskip \@tocrmarg \parfillskip -\rightskip }
        {\addvspace{2ex}}
        {\noindent
         \etocifnumbered
            {\llap{\makebox[1pc][l]{\etoclink{\dotuline{\etocthenumber}}}}}%
            {\hspace*{-1pc}}%
         \etoclink{\dotuline{\etocthename }} % <- I leave intentional \space
         \titlerule*[1pc]{.}%
         \nobreak
         \makebox[\@tocrmarg][r]
            {\etoclink{\dotuline{\makebox[\@pnumwidth][c]{\etocthepage}}}}%
         \par}
        {}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
% Link Customization: \hyperlink{chapter.2}{\dotuline{Jump to chapter 2}} 

\tableofcontents
\chapter{Dummy1}
dummy1


\chapter{Dummy2}
dummy2

\chapter*{Dummy3}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Dummy3}
dummy3
\end{document}
```

[image]